# Deserialize a binary breadth-first in functional programming

Tags: functional-programming, scala, binary-tree

A while back, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111137/deserialize-a-binary-tree-breadth-first-in-functional-programming) on Stack Overflow that involved deserializing a binary tree breadth-first using functional programming (the question itself isn't relevant). I'd like to make sure that I'm following functional programming principles and whether or not this is stack-safe. I'd also like to know if I can make my code more performant, less bloated, clearer, etc. If it helps, the question provides [this link](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883654-What-does-1-null-2-3-mean-in-binary-tree-representation-) to explain the algorithm.

I first defined this rather simple tree type. Every child is an instance of `Node`, and the absence of a left or right child is denoted with `Empty`.

```scala
sealed trait Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](data: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
```

And this trait that represents a function that takes the current list of serialized items (every item is an `Option`, with `None` meaning there is no child). It consumes one or more of these items and returns the rest, along with an `Either`, where a `Right` contains a fully built tree, and a `Left` contains another `RecFun` that will later consume more items to finish building the current tree.

```scala
trait RecFun[T]
    extends (List[Option[T]] => (List[Option[T]], Either[RecFun[T], Tree[T]]))
```

The entry point is `makeTree`. First, a `RecFun` is made using `createRec` below, and the recursive helper inside `makeTree` starts processing the tree from there.

```scala
def makeTree[T](list: List[Option[T]]): Tree[T] = {
  def helper(f: RecFun[T], l: List[Option[T]]): Tree[T] =
    f(l) match {
      case (_, Right(tree)) => tree
      case (next, Left(f))  => helper(f, next)
    }

  list match {
    case Some(x) :: tail => helper(createRec(x), tail)
    case _               => Empty
  }
}
```

`createRec` takes the value of the root node of a subtree, and makes a `RecFun` to continue building it.

```scala
def createRec[T](data: T): RecFun[T] = {
  //No more children, so return a Right with a node whose children are Emptys
  case None :: Nil | Nil => (Nil, Right(Node(data, Empty, Empty)))
 //There's a left child, but no right child to be had, so return here too
  case Some(l) :: Nil => (Nil, Right(Node(data, Node(l, Empty, Empty), Empty)))
  case lo :: ro :: rest => //Possible left child :: possible right child :: rest of the items
    //Return the rest, and an Either depending on what lo and ro are
    (rest, (lo, ro) match {
      case (Some(l), Some(r)) =>
        //Both children exist, so wait for both of them before building the tree
        Left(waitForChildren(data, createRec(l), createRec(r)))
      case (Some(l), None) =>
        //Need to wait only for left child
        Left(waitForChild(Node(data, _, Empty), createRec(l)))
      case (None, Some(r)) =>
        //Need to wait only for right child
        Left(waitForChild(Node(data, Empty, _), createRec(r)))
      //Both children don't exist, so build tree and return right now
      case (None, None) => Right(Node(data, Empty, Empty))
    })
  }
```

This helper simply combines functions that build a tree where the root's value is known, but the children are not.

```scala
//Here, both the children need to be deserialized and have their own RecFuns
def waitForChildren[T](data: T, leftF: RecFun[T], rightF: RecFun[T]): RecFun[T] =
  input => {
    //Attempt to deserialize the left child first
    val (next, res) = leftF(input)
    res match {
      //If it succeeded, use waitForChild to wait for the right child
      case Right(tree) =>
        (next, Left(waitForChild(Node(data, tree, _), rightF)))
      //Otherwise, try to deserialize the right child, then run the new left RecFun leftF2 again
      case Left(leftF2) => {
        val (next2, res2) = rightF(next)
        //Return the rest of the list, along with the new RecFun
        (next2, Left(res2 match {
          //If the right child is constructed, wait for the left child to be constructed
          case Right(tree)   => waitForChild(Node(data, _, tree), leftF2)
          //Otherwise, run leftF2 first, then the new right RecFun rightF2
          case Left(rightF2) => waitForChildren(data, leftF2, rightF2)
        }))
      }
    }
  }
```

Here, one child is known, and we're just waiting for another.

```scala
/**
 * @param ctor Function that takes a child and finishes building parent tree
 * @param f    Function to construct child
 */
def waitForChild[T](ctor: Tree[T] => Node[T], f: RecFun[T]): RecFun[T] =
  input => {
    //Try deserializing the child based on the function f
    val (next, res) = f(input)
    (next, res match {
      //If it's fully built, build the parent tree by applying ctor to it
      case Right(tree)  => Right(ctor(tree))
      //Otherwise, wait for the new RecFun
      case Left(recFun) => Left(waitForChild(ctor, recFun))
    })
  }
```

Here is the code I used for testing:

```scala
val tree = Node(
  1,
  Node(2, Node(3, Node(5, Empty, Empty), Empty), Node(4, Empty, Empty)),
  Empty
)
val tree2 = makeTree(List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3), Some(4), Some(5), None))

println(tree2)
assert(tree == tree2)
```

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sNxnUMZUS6Cout7KZCYHIA) is a Scastie.